# react+express proxy not working(not using setupProxy.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy

Proxy is not working. I am not using http-proxy-middleware.

Error:

> POST http://localhost:3000/db 404 (Not Found)

**router.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/db', (req, res) => {console.log("/db");});
});

module.exports = router;
```

**server.js**

```
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './../../public')));
app.use("/", router)
app.use(createProxyMiddleware("/db", { target: 'http://localhost:4000', changeOrigin: true }));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Check out the app at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: your target url should be your api_host, not http://localhost:4000

Comment: target: 'http://localhost:3000'....this?